# Apache Tomcat 9.0 Startup Issues

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I have installed Apache Tomcat 9.0 on Windows 10. Thus far all I have done is the install and started the service. The service starts and says it's running, but accessing Tomcat Manager or the Welcome Page produces a 404 error. There are clearly errors in the Tomcate9-stderr logs, but I have no idea what the issue may be. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times to no avail. Here is an excerpt from the log files:

```
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.781 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.54
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.783 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 28 2021 13:51:49 UTC
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.783 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.54.0
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.783 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_231-b11
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: abort
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512m
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx2048m
02-Dec-2021 07:44:18.799 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin;C:\gurobi811\win64\bin;C:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\artools;C:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem;C:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\pluginsvr;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\BMC Software\ARSystem\dataimporttool;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\JScot\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.5.6\resources\app\git\cmd\;C:\Users\JScot\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Users\JScot\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Progress\DataDirect\ODBC_80\drivers;C:\Users\JScot\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.1\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.]
02-Dec-2021 07:44:19.042 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
02-Dec-2021 07:44:19.063 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [436] milliseconds
02-Dec-2021 07:44:19.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
02-Dec-2021 07:44:19.086 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
02-Dec-2021 07:44:19.095 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
02-Dec-2021 07:44:19.198 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1933)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:477)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:226)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1840)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1298)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Sourc
```

Comment: Can you check in your lib folder of tomcat you have the servlet-api.jar It can't found that specific Jar. Maybe reinstalling the Tomcat will work

Comment: Thank you for your fast response; Yes, the servlet-api.jar file is in the lib folder.

Comment: Did you put anything else except `tomcat-juli.jar` and `bootstrap.jar` in Tomcat's `CLASSPATH`? The line numbers indicate, that Tomcat is looking in the _system_ classloader, which is the parent of the _common_ classloader. Look in the _"Java"_ tab of Tomcat Monitor (Procrun).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I took the defaults: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded Java from 1.8.0_231 to 1.8.0_311 and Tomcat started working. Unsure why upgrading Java did the trick, but it did.